# Application is not loading when deployed via azure app service

Tags: azure, vue.js, github, deployment, github-actions

I'm a newbie to Azure

I created a new Vue project using `vue create`  which runs locally and even serving the dist folder too it run successfully. (serve -s dist)

And then I deployed the application using GitActions to Azure(Web App Service) which Azure DevOps services indicated that the deployment has been successful:
[azure-devops-service-github-actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz0ht.png)

So I was expecting to see the default page as:
[vue-app-default-page-content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qFTB.png)

Instead, it still shows as:
[azure-site-landing-page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGbXv.png)

There are no error messages, and I'm not sure how best to debug what has gone wrong with a deployment. Also not sure if later when I use the application with any REST APIs does it include any configurations to get it up and running.

---

Secondly, not a blocker, but after removing these lines from the workflow - master.yml file the deployment continued without any issue. Used Node 12 and Node 14. I Googled and have no idea why??

```
- name: Upload artifact for deployment job
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: node-app
        path: .
```

It was causing as the below error and continuously re-run everytime without exiting(re-trying to complete the process):

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:201:27) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

PS: Tried with azure static web apps which is working like a champ! But for me, there is a bit of a challenge in using a static web app for now. So for that reason, I need to stick with Azure web app services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add startup command, you can try it.

```
npx serve -s
```

Or

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa
```

**Related Posts.**

[1. Default Documents (custom 404) on Azure AppService Linux website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65975898/default-documents-custom-404-on-azure-appservice-linux-website/66024272#66024272)

[2. pm2 not found on Azure App service with Node 14 runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66871045/pm2-not-found-on-azure-app-service-with-node-14-runtime/66880978#66880978)

[3. linux azure web app not showing my reactjs app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66647642/linux-azure-web-app-not-showing-my-reactjs-app/66666471#66666471)

Comment: Thank you, tried with the second command and it helped. Now I'm able to see my page  
Their documentation doesn't mention anything about this anywhere that I could find.
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: **Jason Pan:** I secondly mentioned an issue that I faced in the workflow - master.yml file.
Can you help me to understand what might have gone wrong? Because the code was auto-generated from Azure which was causing the error and I manually needed to remove it to get it to work.

Comment: @Markose I may not know the problem you describe, I know very little about github action. Regarding your doubts, you can describe them in detail, send a new post, and more users will answer for you.

Comment: No worries  Thanks

Comment: I've shared this with MSFT on GitHub as well. Someone else there suggested the same thing and it solved the issue immediately. I was unable to find any documentation related to this issue anywhere on their official docs. 
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/51639#issuecomment-823710896

Comment: might be obvious to others, I didn't know how to make this a startup command.
There is a "Configuration" page for my app service on portal.azure.com, on that page you can set startup commands.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason you need to add

```
--no-daemon -i max
```

Works for me as:

```
pm2 start /home/site/wwwroot/app.js --no-daemon -i max
```