# How to deploy Vue application to Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a static Vue web app, I want to deploy it to Azure App Service - not Static Web App because I don't have a Github and I don't want to.

I have followed the guide here ([MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=linux&pivots=development-environment-vscode)), deployment works fine, but I'm not getting anything on the website. It's just a default page showing "Hey, Node developers! Your app service is up and running". What am I missing?

The code runs fine on my local. I can "npm run build", take the dist folder, dump it into a server's IIS wwwroot and it works fine. I'm just having problem to deploy it to Azure App Service.

Edit: Found the answer: [Application is not loading when deployed via azure app service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66924180/application-is-not-loading-when-deployed-via-azure-app-service)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application is not loading when deployed via azure app service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66924180/application-is-not-loading-when-deployed-via-azure-app-service)